# getting an error KeyError: 'the label [False] is not in the [index]'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and I want to find the maximum value of a column and corresponding index.
I used this code:

```
df2=df2.loc[df2.diff==(df2['diff'].max())]
df2.index
```

but I'm getting this error:

> KeyError: 'the label [False] is not in the [index]'

Comment: How working `df2['diff'].idxmax()` ?

Comment: yeah...this worked for me..but I wanna know why that code isn't working

Comment: I guess `df2.diff` return difference, because `.diff` function. So need `df2.loc[df2['diff']==(df2['diff'].max())]`